# Why are random words underlined Office Word spell check?

Tags: microsoft-word

In the example file [here](https://filedropper.com/d/s/FQx0paHMqAQ9jZTmrPIFXEJha5snyQ), why are so many well-spelled words underlined by the spell-checker?
The example is in French but those are common words that can hardly be mispelled.

I tried resetting the proofing language to French after CTRL+a, also tried unchecking the
'do not check spelling or grammar' option as per [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-underlines-words-that-are-spelled-correctly/9064267b-b000-4df7-b42d-676ad34dff26).

Comment: Please replace the filedropper link with an image embedded into your question.

Comment: Be sure to also turn off the option to automatically switch languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word indeed shows lots of spelling errors on your French text:

[image]

The reason is that the text is encoded in UTF-8 and not in ANSI.
Your document is encoded as ANSI, but it contains UTF-8 characters.
Word somehow detects the presence of UTF-8 and displays the characters
correctly.

For example, the word that you see as "Enfin" is not 5 characters,
it is only 4 characters. The third character is
[U+FB01 LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI](https://codepoints.net/U+FB01#:%7E:text=U%2BFB01%20LATIN%20SMALL%20LIGATURE%20FI%20U%2BFB01%20was%20added,and%20is%20mainly%20used%20in%20the%20Latin%20script.)
that takes up two bytes and looks like: "ﬁ".

This text looks like someone is playing a joke, using Unicode.

Comment: It could a case where someone is playing a joke, as you say; but it could also just be a case where the text was copied or converted from, e.g., a PDF that had been created from a document where ligatures were used.

Comment: ^^^^ I have often seen this kind of behaviour in PDFs extracted to DOCX